# ColData, RowData, ColSel, RowSel DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, msflexgrid

I'm trying to convert some VB6 codes to C#, but I got stuck on some MSFlexGrid keyword to translate them to equivalent DataGridView.

Could anyone tell me the DataGridView equivalent for the keywords below?

ColData, RowData, ColSel, RowSel.

Answer (score 0):

ColSel Returns or sets the start or end column for a range of cells.

RowSel Returns or sets the start or end row for a range of cells.
These properties are not available at design time.

Syntax

```
object.ColSel [= value]

object.RowSel [= value]
```

Syntax for the ColSel and RowSel properties has these parts:

Returns or sets an arbitrary long value associated with each row, column, or band. These properties are not available at design time.
    Syntax

```
object.ColData(number) [=value]

object.RowData(number) [=value]

object.BandData(number) [=value]
```

try this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239904(v=vs.60).aspx
and this one : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240146(v=vs.60).aspx